# How to convert a list of list of strings into integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is a list that I have  [['1.0\n'],['2.0\n'],['3.0\n']] and  I would like to convert them into integers 1 2 3 without comma separation and \n.

I'm not sure how to do this conversion as there's a list within a list and I don't really know how to get rid of \n altogether. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want `[[1], [2], [3]]`, you can try

```
lst = [['1.0\n'],['2.0\n'],['3.0\n']]
res = [[int(float(j.replace("\n", ""))) for j in i] for i in lst]
```

if you want `[1, 2, 3]`, you can try

```
lst = [['1.0\n'],['2.0\n'],['3.0\n']]
res = [int(float(i[0].replace("\n", ""))) for i in lst]
```

Comment: Thank you for your variety of answers. This is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you want rounding or not and or a new list. Is there a reason why you have a list in a list? But you'd do something like this

```
x = [['1.0\n'],['2.0\n']]
y = [] 

for item in x:
    tmp = item[0].replace('\n','')
    y.append(int(float(tmp)))

print(y)
```

Comment: I imported csv file to my code and I put them into dataframe I think that's why it is a list in a list. Anyways your answer helps a lot thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

## Removing `/n` and consolidate to a single list

You could solve this with [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

```
list = [['1.0\n'], ['2.0\n'], ['3.0\n']]

my_list = [int(float(value[0].strip())) for value in list]

print(my_list)
```

**Output:** `[1, 2, 3]`

The main things to note in this solution are:

- The nested lists are iterated through, selecting the first element of each with `value[0]`.
- Each iteration:

  - **Value:** `'1.0\n'` is stripped of the `\n` with `value[0].strip()`
  - **Value:** `1.0` is then converted to a float `float(value[0].strip())`
  - **Value:** `1` is then converted to a integer `int(float(value[0].strip()))`

## Without comma separation

```
list = [['1.0\n'], ['2.0\n'], ['3.0\n']]

my_list = [int(float(value[0].strip())) for value in list]

my_string = " ".join(str(value) for value in my_list)

print(my_string)
```

**Output:** `1 2 3`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way:

```py
ls=[['1.0\n'],['2.0\n'],['3.0\n']]
result=[]
for ll in ls:
    [result.append(int(float(l.replace('\n','')))) for l in ll]
print(result)

Output: [1, 2, 3]
```

This code just works under this condition: **[if every element in the list has `\n`]**

Like Raya's answer, I use the `int(float(l))` way, if every element has  '.0', you can also use `l.replace('\n','').replace('.0','')`.